# Write a script to recursively list directories and files within it in Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch script that **recursively** lists all directories and their files with `*.js` type in the below format:

For example, if I start with the `C:\project` directory

```
c:\project
project.js
project_time.js

c:\project\core
core.js
core_render.js
core_application.js
```

I tried to implement the above logic in code as follows:

```
@echo off

for /r %%f in (*.js) do (
  echo %%f >> names.txt
)

pause
```

I was not able to print the directory under which the files are listed.

Comment: You will have to set what the current file path is to a variable. Then check if that variable is equal to the current file it is iterating.  When it is not, then echo the file path and set the variable to the new file path.

Comment: `TREE /F` will do this.

Comment: Also, `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path '.'"` may give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "lastdir="

(   for /r %%A in (*.js) do (
        set "nextdir=%%~dpA"

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if /i not "!lastdir!" == "!nextdir!" (

            rem Empty line and directory path.
            if defined lastdir @echo(
            @echo !nextdir!
        )
        endlocal

        rem Filename.
        @echo %%~nxA

        set "lastdir=%%~dpA"
    )
) > "names.txt"
```

The `lastdir` variable is to record the last directory path so it is echoed only once.

If `lastdir` is different to `%%~dpA`:

- If `lastdir` is defined, then an empty line will be echoed.
- Directory path of found file is echoed.

Filename is always echoed.

`for` modifiers `dp` is the drive and path. `nx` is the name and extension.

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is used only where needed so paths with `!` are not vulnerable.

I am not going to suggest a command line solution as it would be very long. Instead suggest use of `tree` command if the output format is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested example, *(I'm not expecting it to be quick if your base directory is large)*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
(
    For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D "C:\Project" 2^> NUL') Do (
        %__AppDir__%where.exe /Q "%%G":*.js 1> NUL 2> NUL
        If Not ErrorLevel 1 (
            Echo/
            Echo %%G
            For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%H In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe "%%G":*.js')Do (
                Echo %%~nxH
            )
        )
    )
) 1> "names.txt"
Pause
```

If you prefer to run something from the Command Prompt, then try this version:

```batch-file
(For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir /B/S/AD "C:\Project" 2^>NUL')Do @(%__AppDir__%where.exe /Q "%G":*.js >NUL 2>&1&&(Echo/&Echo %G&For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %H In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe "%G":*.js')Do @Echo %~nxH)))>"names.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to do this:

```
dir /S *.js
```

You get the answers, just as you requested.

```
FORFILES /S /M *.js /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

You get complete path for every file.